# How to fix Sagemaker's "No finished training job found associated with this estimator" error?

Tags: machine-learning, python, supervised-learning, aws, sagemaker

I ran a complete AWS SageMaker Autopilot experiment. I now want to generate batch forecasts using this model but I get the error: "No finished training job found associated with this estimator. Please make sure this estimator is only used for building workflow config".

I'm using this [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/gs-console.html) as reference.

Here's my SageMaker Studio notebook Python code.

```
import sagemaker 
from sagemaker import get_execution_role
import boto3 
import os
from time import gmtime, strftime, sleep

session = sagemaker.Session()
bucket = sagemaker.Session().default_bucket()
prefix = "trial-01"
region = sagemaker.Session().boto_region_name
role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()

# The location of the test dataset
batch_input = 's3://{}/{}/test'.format(bucket, prefix)

# The location to store the results of the batch transform job
batch_output = 's3://{}/{}/batch-prediction'.format(bucket, prefix)

container=sagemaker.image_uris.retrieve("xgboost", region, "1.2-1")

test_model=sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(
    image_uri=container,
    role=role,
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge',
    volume_size=5,
    output_path=batch_output,
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker.Session()
)

transformer = test_model.transformer(
    instance_count=1, 
    instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge', 
    output_path=batch_output
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to train your model first. To do that in sagemaker, you can do the following. I assume that you want to train a machine learning model without using a python script as an entry point.

First, define your hyper-parameters :

```
test_model.set_hyperparameters(
    max_depth = 5,
    eta = 0.2,
    gamma = 4,
    min_child_weight = 6,
    subsample = 0.7,
    objective = "binary:logistic",
    num_round = 1000
)
```

Then you have to define your train and validation inputs. for example :

```
train_input = TrainingInput(
    "s3://{}/{}/{}".format(bucket, prefix, "data/train.csv"), content_type="csv"
)
validation_input = TrainingInput(
    "s3://{}/{}/{}".format(bucket, prefix, "data/validation.csv"), content_type="csv"
)
```

Finally, you have to call the .fit() method to train your model :

```
test_model.fit({"train": train_input, "validation": validation_input}, wait=True)
```

In case that you want to train a model through a python script (an entry point), you can refer to this example : https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-script-mode/tree/master/tf-sentiment-script-mode